# Подключение к базе тестового сервера BitrixVM через OpenServer

Tags: битрикс, openserver

Развернул тестовый сервер bitrixvm5. 
В файле settings.php https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyIV0.png прописаны настройки подключения к БД.

Хочу открыть и просмотреть используемую базу данных. Пытаюсь подключиться через OpenServer.

Сам сайт открывается по пути 192.168.16.52. 
Вот консоль тестового сервера - https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYGkI.png

В OpenServer пытаюсь создать соединение https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdPnz.png, но никак не могу подключиться.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне подключиться к БД, что я упустил?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А вместо localhost не следует ли указать IP?

Comment: Получилось решить самостоятельно.
Вот шаги.
Создаем новое соединение.
- http://i.imgur.com/74hDn1A.png
- http://i.imgur.com/y5Iv4S7.png